# Redirect a user to an external site while linking to an internal page?

Tags: php, url, redirect, seo

How can I redirect a user to an external site while linking to an internal page ?

I have seen examples like:

- example.com/go/ksdjfksjdhfls
- example.com/?go=http://www.new-example.com
- ... And many more...

How this is achieved in php ?

Does this have any pros/cons with regards to SEO ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in this approach, but there are a few ways to achieve it.  To do it with the `GET` query, you would simply need the following code:

#### HTML:

```
  <a href="http://example.com/link.php?site=http://www.google.com">Google!</a>
```

#### PHP:

```
if (filter_var($_GET['site'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
          header('Location: ' . $_GET['site']);
}
```

With the above example, it will actually take the user to that location, not to:

```
 http://example.com/link.php?site=http://www.google.com
```

To achieve the url being "local" while pulling up a remote site, you'd either have to:

- Mess with URL rewriting, which can get messy and I'm not sure will let you do the above
- Retrieve the remote page via curl and display it, which may screw up links on the "remote" page
- Use iframes and set the iframe to be the size of the page. Note that this last method, while least offensive, is recognized as a potential security breach known as 'clickjacking' since it's used to trick users into clicking on a link for one page which his hiding a malicious link to another site. Many servers and browsers are taking steps to avoid this (for instance, google does not allow iframing of its home page), so this may also reach dead ends.

So of the three server-side methods I can think up, one may or may not be possible, and is a pain. One will be crippled and put a heavy load on the server.  The last is a known bad guy and is likely not to work for many cases.

So I'd just go with a redirect, and really, if you don't need the address bar to show the local URL, then I'd just have a direct link.

All of the raises the question: What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I think my selection of words had given you a bit of confusion. When I said "while linking to an internal page" I mean have a link like http://example.com/link.php?site=http://www.google.com (it belongs to the site) but after click the user get redirected (on your example to Google). The link still pointing to the local site and not directly to the external site. I hope do you get me now. Any way, Thanks, your answer had cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

put this is beginning before any output to browser

```
<?
header('location:example.com\index.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up an index php file which sets the header location to the url in the get parameter.

example.com/?go=http://www.new-example.com :

```
// example.com/index.php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
    $go = $_GET['go'];
    header('Location: $go');
} // else if other commands
// else (no command) load regular page
?>
```

example.com/go/ksdjfksjdhfls :

```
// example.com/go/ksdjfksjdhfls/index.php
<?php
header('Location: http://someurl.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use .htaccess rules for this. No PHP needed.

i.e.

```
Redirect 307 /go/somewhere-else http://www.my-affiliate-link.com/
```

So visiting `http://www.mywebsite.com/go/somewhere-else` will redirect to `http://www.my-affiliate-link.com/`.

On my site, I use "nofollow" to tell the search engines not to follow the link. The `307` status code means "temporary redirect".

`<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/go/somewhere-else" rel="nofollow">Click here!</a>`

Comment: Yhea but that will means that I will have to generate manually those redirections rules on the .htaccess file, I think the "php way" offers fore flexibility, at least I will not need to modiffy the file each time a new redirection is needed.

Comment: @user983248 That's fine, it depends on how many pages you want to redirect and what you're trying to accomplish. Just offering an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

example.com/?go=http://www.new-example.com

you can use iframe and set the src attribute to http://www.new-example.com

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
   <iframe src="http://www.new-example.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This type of overlay is being watched for now, both remotely and by local browser, as it is a security risk.